# Semantics of exclusive or

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

How do I get a description of $\text {XOR}$ (exclusive or) only using the operators $\wedge$, $\vee$, $\neg$, $\rightarrow$

And is it possible to prove the correctness of such description?

Comment: Have you tried to come up with such a "description" in terms of other operators yourself?

Comment: The correctness of such a paraphrase would most easily be proved by a truth table.

Comment: [Exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) will be true exactly when one of the two disjuncts is true (but not  both). This is the definition in terms of truth-conditions (i.e. the "specification" for the truth table).

Comment: @lemontree I have so far been able to get descriptions using ∧ , ∨, ¬ but not →. For example: (p ∨ q) ∧  ¬(p ∧ q)

Comment: $(p \lor q) \land \neg (p \land q)$ uses no more operators than $\land, \lor, \neg \to$ and therefore fulfills your requirement, it doesn't hurt at all if it doesn't use all of them (like $\to$)... What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want a situation where all four operators fulfill the requirement... if possible

Comment: Change $\lnot (p \land q)$ with $(p \to \lnot q)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks

Comment: Or, for that matter, exploit that $F$ is always equivalent to $F\land(x \to(x\lor \neg x))$, so you can wrap _any expression whatsoever_ into an equivalent one that uses all four connectives.

Answer (score 0):

It is useless to look for correctness here.

" Exclusive OR" is simply the name that has been given to the following truth function , more precisely to the function from {T,F}²  to {T,F} such that :

(T,T) -->  F

(T,F) -->  T

(F,T) -->  T

(F,F) -->  F

Look at this sagittal representation of the XOR function and ask yourself : what does it mean to say that (A XOR B) is true?  If I say that :  (A XOR B) , I say something true if and only if it is the case that : .....

If you compare the truth table of the  X-OR operator to the truth table of the OR operator, you will see that **X-OR is more demanding:** in order  A XOR B to be true, you need (1) what is required in order A OR B to be true, (2) plus an additional condition ...

So to find your translation, you only have to ask yourself: **what does the X-OR operator add  to the OR operator?** In other words, what happens when an OR ( a disjunction) becomes **EXCLUSIVE** ( that is, is no longer inclusive)?